# .Net | Crypto | ECC | How to perform ECC Encryption Decryption using .net framework?

Tags: .net, cryptography, .net-4.0, elliptic-curve

Does **.Net** supports **ECC encryption-decryption** using its framework?
I have seen implementation using bouncy-castle,but need Microsoft provider.
If it is possible,please, suggest me an example.
Also, can we create an ECC public-private key pair using .NET Framework 4.0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in ECC **encryption** in .NET.

- `ECDsa`, and derived types, can be used for digital signatures. (.NET Framework and .NET Core)
- `ECDiffieHellman`, and derived types, can be used for key agreement (.NET Framework only, .NET Core TBD)

No other ECC algorithms are represented by framework types.

Comment: Is microsoft planning to support ECC enc-dec in its framework in future releases ?

Comment: I don't know if any specific plans. If you have specific algorithms you would like to be supported you can make requests via issues at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx